# How do I add the filename after the content of the first column?

Tags: text-processing, columns

This is my original file called `NAME.xxx`
`columnname1 columnname2 columnname3
XX_XX_XX_XX  number      number
YY_YY_YY_YY  number      number
ZZ_ZZ_ZZ_ZZ  number      number`

This is how I would like to have my file
`columnname1      columnname2 columnname3
XX_XX_XX_XX_NAME  number      number
YY_YY_YY_YY_NAME  number      number
ZZ_ZZ_ZZ_ZZ_NAME  number      number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==1{ sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", FILENAME) }{ $1 = $1"_"FILENAME }1' name.xxx
```

- `FILENAME` - input filename (i.e. `name.xxx`)
- `sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", FILENAME)` - truncate filename's extension
- `$1 = $1"_"FILENAME` - append the filename part `FILENAME` to the end of the 1st field `$1`